# Google Maps Engine Linked KML with Labels from Google Maps Engine Pro

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-engine

I have a Maps Engine Pro account and Maps Engine account. I have exported a KML in my Maps Engine Pro account, and linked it to my Maps Engine account. However, the labels are gone. I don't know what I did wrong. I just exported it and added it as linked KML in my Maps Engine account.

Is there any other method to export it with labels included?

My Maps Engine Pro Map: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zw7uoGNV7Gvo.kuA1Rc-lcUsI

My Maps Engine Map (KML linked from Pro): https://mapsengine.google.com/17062274333601359731-05414812628978701557-4/mapview/?authuser=0

As you can see, I have labels in m Maps Engine Pro. But if you check it in Maps Engine, it doesn't show anymore.